# How do I label angles?

Tags: labels

I have the following command:

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw (0,0) node[anchor=north]{$A$} -- (2,0) node[midway,below] {6}

-- (2,0) node[anchor=north] {$B$} -- (0,2) node[midway,right] {10}

-- (0,2) node[anchor=south] {$C$} -- (0,0) node[midway, left] {8}

--cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I label my angles?

Comment: Use [tikzeuclide](https://ctan.org/pkg/tkz-euclide?lang=en).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to use the `angles` library. To this end, I introduced named coordinates and turned the nodes into labels (and removed some duplicated coordinates). You can adjust the parameters like `angle eccentricity` and `angle radius` to achieve your preferred outcome.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[ang/.style={draw, angle eccentricity=1.5,angle radius=0.6cm}]

\draw (0,0) coordinate[label=below:{$A$}](A) --  node[below] {6}
    (2,0) coordinate[label=below:{$B$}](B) --  node[right] {10}
    (0,2) coordinate[label=above:{$C$}](C) --  node[left] {8} cycle
    pic ["$\alpha$",ang]{angle=B--A--C}
    pic ["$\beta$",ang]{angle=C--B--A}
    pic ["$\gamma$",ang]{angle=A--C--B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]